# Call method after submitting form Rails

Tags: forms, controller, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following model:

```
class Coupon < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company

  validates :description, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :fine_print, presence: true
end
```

and the following method in the coupon controller:

```
def redeem
  if params[:pin] == @coupon.company.pin
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    flash.now[:notice] = "Incorrect Pin"
    render :show
  end
end
```

This form is in the a view:

```
<%= form_for( @coupon, :url => coupons_redeem_path( @coupon ), :html => { :method => :post } ) do |f| %>
  <%= label_tag("pin", "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag("pin") %>
  <%= f.submit "Close Message" %>
<% end %>
```

I want the form to call the redeem method in the coupons controller when hitting submit but am getting this error:

No route matches [POST] "/coupons/redeem.1"

EDIT

These are my routes:

```
resources :companies do 
  resources :coupons
end
get 'coupons/redeem'
```

Comment: You can't use POST to create resources whose ID you already know. If you wanna go with POST, you'll gonna have to use `:url => coupons_redeem_path`. Can you include your routes for the coupon resource?

Comment: routes have been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your routes, `coupons` are nested resources of `companies`. So you should choose one of these alternatives:

1st:

```
resources :companies do 
  resources :coupons do
    post :redeem, on: :member
  end
end
```

This leads to helpers like this: `redeem_company_coupon_path(company, coupon)` (and send smth there via POST).

If you don't want to include company to your path, you could choose 2nd:

```
resources :companies do 
  resources :coupons
end   
post 'coupons/:id/redeem', to: 'coupons#redeem', as: :redeem_coupon
```

After that you could use `redeem_coupon_path(coupon)` helper